# Setting message_ttl with AnyEvent::RabbitMQ / Net::RabbitFoot

Tags: perl, rabbitmq

I have code that's working just fine setting up and sending to a RabbitMQ using Net::RabbitFoot, however now I want to add a message queue TTL as per  the RabbitMQ - Time-To-Live Extensions [1](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html).

I have read the Net::RabbitFoot and Net::RabbitMQ documentation, and I can't see any way that they allow me to use this. I've searched around for the answer and I can't see anyone even asking this question. I'm hoping that it's possible and I've just missed the obvious thing explanation somewhere...

This is roughly what I'm doing:

```
my $conn = Net::RabbitFoot->new()
    ->load_xml_spec()
    ->connect( 
        host => $host, 
        port => $port, 
        user => $user, 
        pass => $pass,
        vhost => $vhost, 
        tls => 1,
);
my $chan = $conn->open_channel();
$chan->qos( prefetch_count => 1 );

$chan->declare_queue(  
    queue   => $queue,
    durable => 1,
    passive => 0,
    auto_delete => 0,
    message_ttl => 10000,  # wishful thinking (10 seconds)
);

$chan->declare_exchange(
   exchange => $exchange,
   type     => "fanout",
   auto_delete => 0,
);

$chan->bind_queue(
    queue    => $queue,
    exchange => $exchange,
    routing_key => ""
);

# ...

$chan->publish(
    body => $message,
    exchange => $exchange,
);
```

This declares the queue, exchange, binds them and then publishes to them.  I'd like to add the time to live to the queue when I create/establish/connect to it, but that doesn't seem to work.

I suspect that I will have to send the ttl through via some sort of clever internals manipulation, but if there's an easier way I'd love to know it.

Thank you!

Comment: I still have no idea whether this is possible within code, but I have discovered that I can add a policy on my queue with the message_ttl of the desired time.

So that's probably the obvious thing I was missing.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

it is not documented, but you set the "expiration" header to a ms value, as explained here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html

the interface provided by AnyEvent::RabbitMQ makes it look like this

```
$channel->publish(
    exchange => "exchange_name",
    body => "string goes here",
    header => { expiration => 10_000 }
);
```

for a 10 second TTL on that message, where $channel is an instance of  AnyEvent::RabbitMQ::Channel